# load a different view controller or tableview depending on previous button pressed

Tags: swift, uitableview, subclass, viewcontroller

I am very new to swift coding.  That being said, I'm looking to transition from a "home page" to a tableview or new view controller once a menu item has been selected.  I am just curious how I would go about using one view controller/tableview but loading the contents from an inherited file based on the selection made previous.

Example:
HOME - Chores at home
     - Chores at work
     - Chores at school

A selection of chores at home is selected, then only one segue that is prepared loads the only view controller downstream in Xcode, but loads the content differently then if they had selected chores at work.  Hope that makes sense and thank you very much in advance.  If I am not mistaken, this would be considered subclasses a UIViewcontroller or UItableview???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may Only needs to see UITableView Docs, you can set different datasource depends on your selection 
This is Apple link for docs
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/

And here is simple tutorial to follow

http://www.codingexplorer.com/getting-started-uitableview-swift/

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but it did help lead me to what I needed, so thanks.  I'll post how I made it work below.